# Script is ending with a highlighted '%' how can I debug this?

Tags: linux

My script is pretty lengthy and works properly, however, no matter where my script ends (via normally, or by trap) the last character printed to the console is always a highlighted `%`.

If one has a very long and complex script, how should one go about debugging this?  The only thing I've changed is the replacing of `echo` with `printf` since I read that I should be doing this going forward.

Comment: Use `set -x` to start debugging in a certain line and `set +x` to turn it off.

Comment: Are you using zsh by chance? zsh prints a highlighted `%` when the output from the program being run does not end with a newline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using zsh, if there is output from a command and it does not end in a newline, zsh will print a highlighted `%` and move to the next line:

[image: zsh]

To fix this, make sure your output ends with a newline.

Compare with bash's less elegant handling of the situation:

[image: bash]

Comment: Perhaps less "elegant", but also less "surprising". The script writer knows that `echo -n` means "print without a newline", and is not expecting "print with a highlighted `%` and then a newline, even if I requested no newline". Of course, a well written script will avoid this situation by making sure the last line it outputs always includes a newline, but still...